# filtering on bar highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, rally

In the image it showing the bar chart, each color have different filter like major, minor, incidental and none.
Now I want to add some more different filters on top of already existing filters
Any help on this, thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Create jsfiddle demo with working code, otherwise we don't know what exactly doesn't work, and what do you mean by filters (colors?).

Comment: @PawełFus - Hi pawel thanks for the reply, I updated my image for your understanding. In this I am using Highcharts stacked column with which I have created this bar chart, this shows bars with diffrent colors, each color shows the count for defect severity which are major, minor and incidental. Likewise this filters or legends major, minor. I have closed, open and submitted filters too.  I want to implement that too in this one.While clicking on each legend it shows only those defect count, likewise functionality I want for open and closed defect filter

Comment: Unfortunately we need your code/demo, because without it we have no chance to debug it.